# Invalid Swift Support - The file libswiftCore.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.2

Am using Xcode 9.2, swift 4. After automatically signing the app and submitting to App Store for review, I get this email with the message: 
"The file libswiftCore.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode".
Can someone help with this challenge. Am developing native IOS app, no xamarin.

And how will I check that libswiftCore.dylib has the correct code signature? How do I rebuild the app with the current public (GM) version of Xcode? Help and solution is needed Please

Comment: are you using a beta version of development tool?

Comment: no. stable version. Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it somehow...

1. I deleted the package, obj, and bin folder.
2. Restored the nuget, using your latest official version 3.0.1 and
   3.1.0.
3. Used Xamarin Studio to archive.
4. From XCode, i open the archive and created the SwiftSupport folder
   and copied
5. all the swift dynamic library files `*.dylib` into it
6. Exported the archive with XCode.
7. Uploaded with application loader

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Ferrakkem Bhuiyan, Can you Kindly show where the find the package, obj and bin folders? and how do I achieve the step 2? what is nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:

1. Delete the obj and bin folder in your iOS project.
2. Check your nuget packages are Xamarin.Swift3 or Xamarin.Swift4.
3. Use "Xamarin Studio" or "Visual Studio for Mac" to archive your app.
4. Open the archive by "Finder".
5. Add a folder named "SwiftSupport" in it. (Don't clone it into the archive)
6. Clone the swift dynamic library files `*.dylib` (which you need) into it.

   **Note**: They should be copied from the right toolchain of Xcode. For example, if your nuget package is Xamarin.Swift3, they should be copied form Xcode 8.3.3 (GM).
7. Exported the archive with "Xcode".
8. Uploaded with "Application Loader".